# Using Web.Config Transforms to Change the "size" element in a log4net "parameter"

Tags: asp.net, web-config-transform, xdt-transform

I'm working on an ASP.NET project which uses log4net. In the Development environment, I want the `size` element of the `@stackTrace` parameter to be set to a higher value than in other environments.

The structure of the log4net.config file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <log4net debug="true">
        <appender name="SQLServerAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
            <parameter>
                <parameterName value="@stackTrace"/>
                <dbType value="String"/>
                <size value="1000"/>
                <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawPropertyLayout">
                    <key value="stackTrace"/>
                </layout>
            </parameter>
            <!-- More parameters -->
        </appender>
    </log4net>
</configuration>
```

I would like to change the `value` attribute of the `size` element to 2000.

I tried the following transform file, but it didn't change anything:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <log4net>
      <appender name="SQLServerAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
        <parameter xdt:Locator="XPath(configuration/log4net/appender[@name='SQLServerAppender']/parameter[parameterName[@value='@stackTrace']])"
                   xdt:Transform="Remove">
        </parameter>
      </appender>
    </log4net>
  </configuration>
```

The "Remove" was a last resort to try to get *something* to happen!

What should I do to perform the desired transform? It's not clear to me how to combine `xdt:Locator` with `xdt:Transform` in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the answer by [Eric.Y.Fan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3190260/eric-y-fan) didn't work, I played around a bit to find out why not.

I first put back the `<connectionString>` value (I left it out of my post for clarity), and it *did* work. That proved that the correct `<appender>` had been found, but that the correct `<parameter>` was not being found. "Found", or "located". That was a hint.

I looked at the XPath expression, and realized that it was attempting to locate the `<parameter>` which had a `<parameterName>` with a `value` attribute with the value `@stackTrace`. So I tried using `Condition`:

```
<parameter xdt:Locator="Condition([parameterName[@value='@stackTrace']])" 
    xdt:Transform="Replace">
</parameter>
```

This worked!

So the final transform is:

```
<parameter xdt:Locator="Condition([parameterName[@value='@stackTrace']])">
    <size value="2000" xdt:Transform="Replace" />
</parameter>
```

Answer (score 1):

I could be mistaken but I don't think Web.config transforms can be applied to other arbitrary xml files.

For that purpose I usually use **SlowCheetah**:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5

It's a great tool, very easy to use (similar to web.config transforms, but can be applied to anything), and also integrates very well with automated builds and deployments.

Here's a guide from Scott Hanselman:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, but we are already using transforms for the log4net.config. I removed the other transforms from the file, for clarity. My problem is with this particular transform.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
<log4net>
  <appender name="SQLServerAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
    <parameter>
       <size value="2000" xdt:Locator="XPath(configuration/log4net/appender[@name='SQLServerAppender']/parameter[parameterName[@value='@stackTrace']])" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes"/>
    </parameter>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```